# asp.net multiple non nested masterpages in one project

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, css

I have an asp.net site built using visual studio 2010 in c#. The site is basically two sections: http://www.wsgelectronics.com for reference.

The default page is the site.master page with default.aspx. I want to split into two more master pages, one for each section, car audio and computer sections if you look at the site, each with its own layout, nav bar, content etc.

How would I go about linking them to work? Can I have three ***.master pages on one project? I didn't choose nested cause they would be completely different layouts, but I cannot find any tutorials on linking different master pages on one site. Can this even be done?

Comment: Not sure if I understand, you need different pages with different maaster pages? That's all?

Comment: one site.master has two links, each which go to their own .master page, and then each section of that site run off that master page its basically two websites combined into one

Comment: the main site.master is basically only the intro page to my site with one default.aspx content page...then there are two master pages one for each section of the site

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can have as many master pages as you need in a given web site. When you create a Web Form (a regular .aspx page) in your site, there's a checkbox for "Select master page", so make sure that's checked. Then, when you pick your desired master page, Studio will stub out the needed markup for your page to use that master page.

For example, here's a stub of a web form that has a master in the same directory, called `MasterPage.master`. The relevant parts are:

1. In the Page directive, the property `MasterPageFile` shows the application relative path to the master page.
2. Master pages can have many server controls of type `ContentPlaceHolder`. This allows you to control where the markup in your pages are displayed.  The master page I used in this example has two, one is called `head` and the other is called `ContentPlaceHolder1`.  Again, those controls are defined in my master page.

Sample markup:

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/MasterPage.master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="Default" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" Runat="Server">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" Runat="Server">
</asp:Content>
```

For more info, see [Master Page Tutorials](http://www.asp.net/master-pages/tutorials) on asp.net.

Comment: well i created the Site.master page and its default.aspx page all working fine, then in visual studio i created two more master pages with different names, in that project by clicking the project/ add new/ master page/ etc and linking them to the correct links, however, when i click the link which should take me to the correct master page i get a parser error

Comment: im sure it has something to do with the page name, the namespace, codebehind

Comment: You can't actually request a master page in a web browser - it does not get served as a regular page. You will need to create a page (Web Form) that uses that master, and then link to that page.

Comment: the intial master page is Site.master, th second is WSGTS.master and the third is WSGSC.master and all the codebehind looks correct for those pages, but it doesnt work

Comment: ok i understand now...i think...i just build the second and third masterpages, and continue with all the content pages, but i have those pull from its particuar master page...not the site.master, that correct...so i dont link to that master page i link to that content page...which is then linked to the correct master page...

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can use multiple master page but at a time one master page should be referenced.
You can inherits multiple master page at code behind by specifying the master page in the `pre_Init` event of page life cycle.

All you need to do is to define a property on the content page which will set the desired Master page in the `pre_Init` event may be a session variable making it dynamic.